# Postfix more Sources in alias_maps, which matches first?

Tags: postfix

I have an entry in my Postfix configuration, as follows:

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_mysql.cf,hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-aliases-map
```

If the same adresses are in both sources, which one will be used? First match oder last match?
If you have the answer for that, please give me a reference where I could find it in the Documentation of Postfix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix will stop after the first map from with he it gets a result, that is, if your maps contain :

```
$ cat a
bob@bar.org    bob
$ cat b
bob@bar.org    bob2
```

and you have `virtual_alias_maps = hash:a hash:b` the result of the lookup for `bob@bar.org` will be "`bob`", not "`bob2`" nor "`bob,bob2`".

I can't seem to find it documented somewhere though.